# How to clean a time column in r

Tags: r

I have a time column in R as:

```
22:34:47
06:23:15
7:35:15
5:45
```

How to make all the time values in a column into hh:mm:ss format. I have used
as_date(a$time, tz=NULL) but I am not able to get the format which I wanted.

Comment: can you provide the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `parse_date_time` which can take multiple formats

```
library(lubridate)
format(parse_date_time(time, c("HMS", "HM"), tz = "GMT"), "%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "22:34:47" "06:23:15" "07:35:15" "05:45:00"
```

#### data

```
time <- c("22:34:47", "06:23:15", "7:35:15", "5:45")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) approach with [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and `hms` verbs.

```
library(dplyr)
library(hms)

a <- tibble(time = c("22:34:47", "06:23:15", "7:35:15", "5:45"))

a %>%
  mutate(
    time = case_when(
      is.na(parse_hms(time)) ~ parse_hm(time),
      TRUE ~ parse_hms(time)
    )
  )

# # A tibble: 4 x 1
#  time  
#  <time>
# 1 22:34 
# 2 06:23 
# 3 07:35 
# 4 05:45
```

> Note that the use of `case_when` could be replaced with an `ifelse`. The reason for this conditional is that `parse_hms` will return `NA` for values without seconds.

You may also want the output to be a `POSIX` compliant value, you may adapt the previous solution to do so.

```
a %>%
  mutate(
    time = case_when(
      is.na(parse_hms(time)) ~ as.POSIXct(parse_hm(time)),
      TRUE ~ as.POSIXct(parse_hms(time))
    )
  )

# # A tibble: 4 x 1
#   time               
#   <dttm>             
# 1 1970-01-01 22:34:47
# 2 1970-01-01 06:23:15
# 3 1970-01-01 07:35:15
# 4 1970-01-01 05:45:00
```

> Note this will set the date to `origin`, which is `1970-01-01` by default.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for a prompt reply. I am getting the following error when I run it.

Comment: is.na(parse_hms(uber$Request.timestamp))~parse_hm(uber$Request.timestamp),
Error: unexpected ',' in "    is.na(parse_hms(uber$Request.timestamp))~parse_hm(uber$Request.timestamp),"
>     TRUE ~ parse_hms(uber$Request.timestamp)
TRUE ~ parse_hms(uber$Request.timestamp)
>   )
Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"
> )
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"

Comment: @ShriramPeddhibhotlaVenkat, I cannot reproduce your error, you appear to have a formatting error

Comment: Hi I corrected the code and ran it again. I get the following error.            
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: could not find function "parse_hms".

Comment: @ShriramPeddhibhotlaVenkat, the function `parse_hms` comes from the `hms` package, you must load it with `library(hms)` first or call it directly with `hms::parse_hms`

Comment: thanks again. Iget the following output.11/7/2016 11:51          NA                                                                                          
 2 11/7/2016 17:57          NA                                                                                          
 3 12/7/2016 9:17           NA                                                                                          
 4 12/7/2016 21:08          NA

Comment: @ShriramPeddhibhotlaVenkat, then my first (`non_POSIX`) option provides that, the `pillar` display for `tibble` isn't showing the seconds in that view, but they are there... `a$time[1] # [1] "22:34:47"`

Answer (score 1):

Nothing a bit of formatting can't take care of:

```
x <- c("22:34:47","06:23:15","7:35:15","5:45")

format(
  pmax(
     as.POSIXct(x, format="%T", tz="UTC"),
     as.POSIXct(x, format="%R", tz="UTC"), na.rm=TRUE
  ),
  "%T"
)
#[1] "22:34:47" "06:23:15" "07:35:15" "05:45:00"
```

The `pmax` means any additional seconds will be taken in preference to just `hh:mm`.

You could get functional if you wanted to get a similar result with less typing, and more opportunity for turning it into a repeatable function.

```
do.call(pmax, c(lapply(c("%T","%R"), as.POSIXct, x=x, tz="UTC"), na.rm=TRUE))
```